# Add WooCommerce registration form to any page/template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

I want to add the user registration form to several pages in WordPress.
Until now, I couldn't find any solution for that.

I tried to copy the form from the WooCommerce login/registration template.
Unfortunately without success.

Is there any way to do this without a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I made a mistake at my first try to solve that problem.

You could copy the form from the file /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php and use it everywhere on the site.

Works fine ;)